# Causative construction with 'get'

Tags: sentence-construction, causative-get

'She made me shoot a rabbit' (here, I don't want to use **make** causative as in my intended meaning, I was not forced but I was hired to shoot the rabbit and another thing, I wish to show that the action of shooting has been completed. But I wanna say this informally so, I choose to go with **get** instead of **have** causative).

1. > 'She got me to shoot a rabbit' ( I think here, 'to shoot' is not giving the sense of Shooting has been done or completed).
2. > 'She got me Shooting the rabbit'(Shooting is in process here,not finished).
3. > 'She got me shooted the rabbit' (It is wrong as 'shooted' is followed by 'the rabbit' and Here, 'shooted' is giving passive sense not active).
4. > 'She got the rabbit killed by me' (I think it is the least wrong one. But It is followed by 'by+agent' and I don't think a causative can followed by it).

with the help of my all four attempts I think you would've got my intended meaning. So, can it be expressed with 'get' causative. And is there any better way to say it?

Comment: Personally, I'd probably say *She **had** me kill the rabbit*. But this question is half Off Topic proofreading and half Off Topic writing advice. There's little to actually be ***learned*** here apart from noting that at least some of OP's suggested phrasings are syntactically invalid.

Comment: Yeah, while writing I too thought it would look as proofreading. But I had to do to better explain myself. All those four attempts wery my research before asking here. And, I added them to help you guys give me the spot-on answer. Yeah, some of them were wrong as I forcely put the intended meaning in every 'get' causative I know. And by writing the reason for why I think them wrong is actually I am asking that I am going on the right track or not. There can be a better way to explain it but for now this was my best effort. And thanks for your reply, it seems 'have' is the best for here.

Comment: I'm not too sure, but I suspect Americans might be more likely to prefer *She **got me to** kill it* (which sounds a bit more "colloquial" to me) rather than *She **had me** kill it* (which is at least *slightly* "starchy / formal", even for me as a Brit).

Comment: I have a question which is loosely related to my original one. I saw in a youtube video that the action of 'to- Infinitives',in a sentence,   happens after the action of main verb. So, if I say 'She got me to kill the rabbit' action of killing will happen after the event of main verb. But does it mean that the verb in infinitive form will surely be done or it has been done (as here the causative verb is in past tense). youtube link: https://youtu.be/1hhLhldDgew and at 4:19 he said that.

Comment: If that youtube video causes you to think the highlighted word in *She got me **to** shoot a rabbit* somehow relates to the fact that whatever she did to make me shoot the rabbit must have happened ***before*** the actual shooting took place, all I can say is it's not a useful video for you to watch. I only listened to a few seconds around the bit you were interested in, so I can't really say if the guy is talking sense or not.

Comment: Thanks for telling me as I had been developing my understanding on Infinitives on that video.

Comment: I will make time to listen to the whole thing. That connection between the infinitive and the future is a new concept to me, but it might be meaningful, i dunno.

Comment: A BIT LATER... Okay, I've listened to the whole video, and yes - what he's saying seems to make sense. It might even be a useful approach to differentiating 1) *She got me to kill rabbits* and 2) *She got me killing rabbits.* Where #1 might imply I only killed rabbits *in the past, at her behest, reluctantly*, but #2 might imply that she simply *introduced me to the possibility* of killing rabbits - which I then actually did, and enjoyed so much that I've been happily killing rabbits every day since! :)

Comment: You might want to have a look at [“Get something to work” vs ”Get something working”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123991/) as asked some years ago on ELU. The main takeaway I get from that page is that even most native speakers wouldn't normally be conscious of any significant difference between the two verb forms there, so you should be careful to avoid thinking there's a very important rule involved here. But the general principle presented by the Youtube guy might help you learn / remember / decide which verbs associate better with the infinitive, and which with the gerund.

Comment: Yeah ,I should stop thinking there's a big difference between them. But Is there any significant difference b/w  'she had me kill/ shoot rabbits' and 'she got me to kill/shoot rabbits'. Or it is just the matter of formal or informal.

Comment: If you ***have*** someone do something, not only is that version significantly more formal - it usually implies you're the one in authority (or the one with the money), and you *instructed* (and/or *paid*) them to do it. The same might apply with ***get***, but that version can also be used if you somehow *persuaded* or *tricked* them into doing what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

(3) is wrong because *shooted* is not a valid verb form. The past tense is *shot.*

(2) *Get someone [verb]ing* doesn't  work for a single action. You could say 'She got me shooting rabbits' meaning that she encouraged me to take up shooting as an activity.

(1) is the best. It doesn't give any sense that the shooting hasn't happened.

(4) puts more emphasis on the death of the rabbit than on the action of shooting.

Comment: in get someone/something [verb]ing I saw an example, 'I got the machine working'.....is it not a single action(progressive action) And, in (3) if I correct It to 'she got me shot the rabbit' would it be then right?

Comment: I should have gone on to say that _she got me shot the rabbit_ doesn't work either. _Got the machine working_ is a continuing or progressive action, and _got me shooting_ implies a repeated or habitual action.

Comment: In (1) you said, "it doesn't give any sense that shooting hasn't happened'....does it mean we can't say, for sure,shooting has happened or not?

Comment: You said _I think here, 'to shoot' is not giving the sense of Shooting has been done or completed_. I said that it _does_ give that sense - that's why I considered it the best way to express your meaning.